# Firebase in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase iOS client in my Xamarin app. I am observing a single event to find out if a name is unique. I need to make sure I push out of the method once the observe is completely finished. Here is code (simplified of course). Any suggestions?

```
private bool checkMethod (String inpName)
{
    bool isNameUnique = true;

    myNode.ObserveSingleEvent (DataEventType.Value, (snapshot) =>
    {
        if (snapshot.ChildrenCount > 0)
        {
            NSEnumerator children = snapshot.Children;
            var childSnapShot = children.NextObject ( ) as DataSnapshot;

            while (childSnapShot != null)
            {
                NSDictionary childDict = childSnapShot.GetValue<NSDictionary> ( );
                String fetchedName = childDict.ValueForKey ((NSString)"name").ToString ( );

                if (fetchedName == inpName)
                {
                    isNameUnique = false;
                    break;
                }
                childSnapShot = children.NextObject ( ) as DataSnapshot;
            }
        }
    });

    return isNameUnique;
}
```

Comment: Can you describe the problem you are seeing? Is it not working, or are you seeing multiple reports, etc?

Comment: I should have worded the issue better. The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to wait until the observer is done and then go out of the method. At the moment, I modify my methods and an await for a random number such as 3 seconds to make sure the observer is completely done. But I need a way to return only when observer has completed its tasks.

Comment: I think in this situation, you should pass in a delegate to call when the event happens.